# Does the Network pursue violations of the Terms of Service?

Tags: discussion

I ran across this e-book today, [*Salesforce Programming: Questions and Answers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xIhRDwAAQBAJ), selling for $4.61, which is nothing more than verbatim copy and paste of questions and answers from our beloved salesforce.stackexchange.com and it seems to violate the Content reproduction rules.

Is this a concern?

https://books.google.com/books?id=xIhRDwAAQBAJ

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) under which Stack Exchange user-contributed content is published allows redistribution, remixing, etc, including commercial use. See [Are these eBooks that copy from SE illegal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273989) with an answer by an employee (which indicates that, at least as of 2016, they were not planning an action against the e-book author).

That said, recently there were [multiple concerns](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10600)   about the compliance of these books with the terms of the license; see the linked discussion (on Physics Meta) for details.

Comment: The new [ToS](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) makes the book possibly illegal. What do you think?

Comment: New ToS does not have any effect on activities that predate it. They may have implications for scraping the content in the future, but not for the sale of content already scraped.

Comment: Well, I'm not a lawyer, I was just asking if books like this in the future might be enforced? While I like to think that I'm above average in at least a few skills, I admit that lawyerese always confuses me.